# get the data passed in url through get method using rest api

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I have integrated rest controller with codeigniter. following is the function for get method

```
public function cource_topics_get($res=1) {
    $this->response(array('status' => 1, 'succ_message' =>  $res));       
}
```

I want to get the data from following link in the above function 
http://localhost/login/index.php/admin/cource_topics?key=value

Help me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally get it using $this->input->get('key');

```
http://localhost/login/index.php/admin/cource_topics?key=value
```

You controller admin and function cource_topics
in your function write

```
$value = $this->input->get('key');
```

Comment: what if the key is changed to name ??

Comment: in that  case if you dont know the key then you can use `$this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: output for $this->uri->segment(3); comes to be false .

Comment: in that case you just need to pass value in url `http://localhost/login/index.php/admin/cource_topics?1323`

Comment: it works with http://localhost/login/index.php/admin/cource_topics/1323

Comment: but i need to get value from get request i.e http://localhost/login/index.php/admin/cource_topics?a=123

Comment: It should... If you don't know the key you can use the one above.

Comment: for using key value in url ie a=123 you should know the key if not then you should use URI segemtn